# Middleman - how to convert blog posts into data/posts.json?

Tags: middleman

**Goal:**
On build, convert blog's front matter into `data/posts.json` so that I can iterate over `data.posts.json` with my shiny *MVCofTheWeek.js*

**Background**
Using the `middleman-blog` gem, trying to convert blog front matter into a json file that's stored in `data/posts.json`

**Problem** I can't seem to access the `blog.articles`, `page_articles`, etc in `config.rb` the way I can in a view (They seem to be on `Middleman::Application::MiddlemanApplication1`). I can't tell if I'm missing the proper helper method or need some extra configuration to get access to blog posts in `config.rb`

**Attempts** So far, I've tried the following but neither have `#blog` in scope:

1. Explored building a [custom extension](https://middlemanapp.com/advanced/custom_extensions/) and trying the `activate`
2. Accessing the posts in the `activate :blog` bloc but that is a different class (`Middleman::Configuration::ConfigurationManager`) and doesn't have `#articles`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up taking a different approach to solve the initial problem. Which was to skip data and just  grab blog.articles and put direclyt in `init.js.erb` files. I also used a helper method to clean it up some.

```
// init.js.erb

var app = app || {};

$(function() {
  'use strict';
  var data = <%= blog_posts_as_json %>; // get data as json

  var posts = _.map(data, function(p) {
    return JSON.parse(p) // parse json and put in var posts
  });
});

## config

helpers do

  def blog_posts_as_json
   blog.articles.map { |b|
      b.data.to_json
    }
  end
end
```

However, this doesn't let me add things like the article summary to the hash so there are some issues to be worked out.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it, but someone has created a "Middleman-API" extension which may do what you're attempting: https://github.com/jordanandree/middleman-api

Another solution which often gets used in Jekyll sites is to build a JSON template file that loops through blog posts. This is typically how client-site search is added to a static site – the resulting JSON file becomes the index that powers the Javascript search widget.

A really simple example would look like this:

```
---
---
[
    {% for post in site.posts %}
    {
      "title"    : "{{ post.title }}",
      "href"     : "{{ post.url }}",
      "date"     : {
         "day"   : "{{ post.date | date: "%d" }}",
         "month" : "{{ post.date | date: "%B" }}",
         "year"  : "{{ post.date | date: "%Y" }}"
      }
    }
    {% unless forloop.last %},{% endunless %}
    {% endfor %}
]
```

This is Jekyll syntax, using Liquid for templating, but you could use ERB, HAML, etc. to do the same thing. `site.posts` would need to be whatever variable you're using to access your blog posts normally. You could add any other fields you wanted to access this way as well, including the entire contents of the post.

You'd want to call this file something like **posts.json.liquid** (or whatever language you're using for templates).

One issue is escaping HTML in your content. That's probably a job for a helper method that calls `to_json` on whatever input you give it.

Some relevant links (again, Jekyll-based, but it's a similar problem):

- http://mathayward.com/jekyll-search/
- https://developmentseed.org/blog/2015/04/20/building-with-jekyll/
- http://jekyll.tips/tutorials/output-as-json/

Comment: I second the escaping concern; strongly recommend creating a helper that returns a Hash and then simply doing `{{ my_posts_helper.to_json }}` in the template.